# ReactJS Collapsible element breaks when setting new title and body in hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is my first React project and I would like to use hooks, but I seem to have an issue with an element

```
function Document(props) {

  const [id] = useState(props.match.params.id);
  const [document, setDocument] = useState(0);

  ///////////////////////////////////////
  useEffect(function getTheDocument() {

    getDocument({
      id,
    }).then(document => {
      setDocument(document.data);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }, [id]);
  ////////////////////////////////////////////

  const [body, setBody] = useState(0);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(0);

  ////////////////////////
  useEffect(function setBodyAndTitle() {

    if (document) {
      setTitle(document.title);
      setBody(document.description);
    }

  }, [document]);
  //////////////////////////

  const changeBody = (data) => {

  ...

  const module = ...

  setTitle(module[0].title);
  setBody(module[0].body);
}

}
```

So that is how I handle the body and title. When a button is clicked, `changeBody` is called which finds an object based on some values and sets a new title and body. But that component which is a simple collapsible menu like this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-collapse. The button is in the collapsible data. Am I handling this wrong? The menu is no longer collapsible all the hidden button can be seen. I expected the title and body to change ... that's all.

Comment: you use id state without setId.. Probably this raise an error in useState function. Could you please to fix it?

Comment: the first useEffect looks weird... You use useEffect inside useEffect??

Comment: No ... element breaks when I use `setTitle` and `setBody` in `changeBody`. I will fix that as well.

Comment: No ... I don't use useEffect inside another useEffect ... I saw this: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html. Maybe I wrote it wrong in the question? Let me see ... I edited my question. Added some slashes around the `useEffects`. I am not using them one inside the other.

Comment: Can you post the entire component? Or better yet, create a minimal, reproducible example in [`CodeSandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard) or another similar site. That would help to figure this out a lot.

Comment: I can't create it in `CodeSandbox` because it depends on some api calls.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to handle states of `title` and `body` if these are a properties of `document` object. The same for `id`, but create an effect to do the request when `id` change and use state for `document` by setting a value for this state inside the effect, and create a state for collapse state.

Here is my code to handle this logic

```
import React from 'react'

function Document({ id = 1 }) {
  const [document, setDocument] = React.useState({})
  const [innerId, setId] = React.useState(() => id)
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = React.useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Call my API request when my ID changes
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"+innerId)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(setDocument)
    console.log("rerender")
  }, [innerId])

  // For demo only, increment the ID every 5 seconds
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() =>setId(i => i+1) , 5000)
    return () => clearTimeout(intervalId)
  }, [])

  const toggle = React.useCallback(() => setCollapsed(c => !c))

  // You can use useMemo hooks to get title and body if you want
  const [title, body] => React.useMemo(
    () => [document.title, document.body]
    , [document]
  )

  return (<article>
    <header>{document.title}</header>
    <hr></hr>
    <p style={{height: collapsed ? 0: "100%", overflow: "hidden"}}> 
        {document.body}
    </p>
    <button onClick={toggle}>Collapse</button>
    </article>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<Document id={1}/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: But they're not properties of `document` ... My document has ... `sub-documents`  with `sub-sub-documents` which have titles and content. That show hide component had these `sub-documents` grouped. Anyway ... thank you for your answer. I added an answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

This is really cool. I'm beginning to like React. Seems that you can create a 
`memoized functional component` https://logrocket.com/blog/pure-functional-components/ which doesn't update if the props don't change. In my case the props don't change at all after the initial render.

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

function PercentageStat({ label, score = 0, total = Math.max(1, score) }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h6>{ label }</h6>
      <span>{ Math.round(score / total * 100) }%</span>
    </div>
  )
}

function arePropsEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return prevProps.label === nextProps.label; 
}

// Wrap component using `React.memo()` and pass `arePropsEqual`
export default memo(PercentageStat, arePropsEqual);
```